# Proof of $\frac{\tanh(x)-1}{e^{-2x}}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have to give a formal proof that the limit of h(x) = $\frac{\tanh(x)-1}{e^{-2x}}$ is -2 as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

For all ε>0 there must be a N>0 such that  |h(x)-(-2)|<ε for all x>N

$$ | \frac{\tanh{x}-1}{e^{-2x}}-(-2) | = | \frac{2}{1+e^{2x}}  |$$

Which means that

$$|\frac{2}{1+e^{2x}}|≤ \frac{2}{2x+2}=\frac{1}{x+1}$$

Therefore, if given $\epsilon$>0 we can always choose N = $\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$

$$ | h(x) + 2 | ≤ \frac{1}{x+1} < \frac{1}{1+N} =  \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1} = \epsilon $$

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Some comments: 1) $\iff$ is a logical operator and doesn't apply to formulae. If you mean those two formulae are equal, just write $=$. 2) You never define $h(x)$. What do you mean by it? 3) $1/\epsilon < \epsilon$ is a very suspicious line, especially when $\epsilon$ is small. It would probably be easier to check correctness if you write the proof out in more detail (e.g. starting from the definition of a limit, explain exactly what you think the limit is, and then go from there).

Comment: No, this needs a lot of work, particularly with regard to grammar because in fact it's really hard to follow what you're saying. You don't prove expressions, you prove statements. I think what you mean in the opening sentence is that you have to evaluate the limit of the expression as $x \to \infty$. The previous commenter gave other points to consider.

Comment: So my N is wrong? Would it be correct to put it as N = 1/  -  1 instead?

Comment: I have now further edited my proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's quite right, but it's close enough that I can comment on it all. The question statement is clear now, and so is your definition of the limit.

Your algebra is right, so we just need to prove that $\frac{2}{1+e^{2x}} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. You said

$$\frac{2}{1+e^{2x}} \le \frac{2}{2x+2}$$

it would be good to say explicitly that this is due to $e^{2x} \ge 1+2x$ (and that this is true for $x>0$).

You then say "we can choose $N=\frac1\epsilon-1$ ... which further means I can always choose $N$ to be $1/\epsilon$" which is a bit confusing. You can't pick $N$ to have two different values. You also say $K$, where I guess you mean $N$, and say $\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}} = \epsilon$ which is clearly wrong. It would be clearer to say,

> Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $N = \frac1\epsilon - 1$. Then for all $x>N$
> $$|h(x)+2| \le \frac{1}{1+x} \le \frac{1}{1+N} = \epsilon$$

Comment: I am sorry for the mistakes, I jumbled it together which caused the confusion. N = 1/ was my original value for N, and N = 1/ -1 is the the new, I mistakenly thought I had deleted the previous one. And I wrote K instead of N, because that's the way my textbook has it, despite N being used more commonly here on the Internet. Thank you a lot for the answer.

Comment: @MarkusJ.Blicher You're welcome, I'm glad it helped!